# Algorithm for all unique combinations in a 5*12 grid

Tags: arrays, algorithm, grid, unique, binomial-coefficients

i'm looking for an algorithm or the name of my problem (i assume this is very old and nothing new).
I want to find all the unique combinations of 5 filled cells in a 5x12 grid.

example:

```
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0


1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0


1|1|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
-----------------------
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

this is also valid
```

and so on. Each occupied cell would be represented as an (X,Y)-Tuple

The corresponding formula for the amount of unique combinations is n over k - binomialcoefficient (or something like that) which would be something like 5.1 million unique combinations if i recall correctly.

Most other similar questions here or on other platforms restrict it some way that each row must have exactly one cell occupied. For my special case thats not true and the reason for my issue.

This is my first question here and i hope someone can help me solve this as i cannot find an idea for a systematic approach

Comment: Is it always going to be five points filled in, and always in a 5-by-12 grid? Or do you need to more generally be able to find all combinations of k points in m-by-n grid? If it's just specifically 5x12 choose 5, you could just use five nested for loops (for a = 1 to end, for b = a+1 to end, for c = b+1 to end ...) and brute-force it.

Comment: For this case its always a 5x12 grid with chosen 5. I thought of the nested for loops but i dont think this approach can handle the combinations where multiple cells are set in one of those defined rows as shown in the last example i gave. I might be wrong though and its just a bit more complex

Comment: The five loops are for the five you are choosing, not the five rows - i.e. the "end" in the loop would be 60, and then you'd map back to the 2D coordinates. But it looks like the guy below already helped you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use this easy and understandable solution:
First of all, give every cell an index so we could talk about 60-cells-length-list instead of a 2-diemensional board. I want you to initial such an indexes-list: [1, 2, 3... 59, 60]
Now, you basically need every k-size (in your case it's five) combination of those indexes.
The rest is pretty easy. Use this code:

```
def findsubsets(s, n): 
    return list(itertools.combinations(s, n))
```

While s is your list and n is the k (5 for you). This function returns every possible combination of 5 numbers from the list.
Use every combination to fill the right cells with 1's and the rest with 0's.
Hope it helped you. Good Luck!

Comment: This sounds very good. I havent thought of simply abstracting from a 2d grid to a one dimensional list. This is probably the solution im going to implement. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!